# Symfony2: use parameter defined in config.xml

Tags: php, parameters, symfony, config

I have a paginator class which should get the limit out of the config.xml and the current page from the controller.

How do I define the limit in config.xml and how can I access it outside the controller?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your paginator class as DIC service and add `service_container` as a service e.g

```
//paginator class 
//namespace definitions
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class Paginator{
    /**
     * @var Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface 
     */
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container){
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function yourPaginationMethod(){
        $limit = $this->container->getParameter("limit.conf.parameter");
        //rest of the method
    }
}
```

And then in you `services.yml` of your bundle.

```
 #services.yml
 paginator_service:
  class: FQCN\Of\Your\PaginatorClass
  arguments: [@service_container]
```

And in your controller you can get access of the `Paginator` in following way.

```
//in controller method
$paginator = $this->get('paginator_service');
```

For more info about it you can check [Service container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) section of Symfony Documentation.

Comment: Passing the entire container might not be such a good idea if you just need a parameter.  You can pass the parameter itself directly to your service with %limit.conf.parameter%